# Porting sklearn SVC with rbf kernel to java

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, classification, svm

I have trained a rbf kernel SVM in python using sklearn and am now porting it to java for production.

When reading the [SVC documentation](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/svm.html#svm-classification) I came across the decision function:

[image]

This seems to indicate that I have to know the weight for every training sample in order to evaluate the SVC, however SVC only exposes the weights for the support vectors through the `dual_coef_` attribute.

Is there anyway to work around this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to know the weight of every training sample. You only need the weight of the support vectors.

The reason is that if a vector `x_i` is not a support vector, then `alpha_i=0` (see page 5 [here](http://www.robots.ox.ac.uk/~az/lectures/ml/lect3.pdf)), and hence `y_i*alpha_i=0` as well. Hence you never use such `x_i` in the classification process (once you fitted the svm).

The rest of the parameters are accessible through svm attributes, as mentioned in the [documentation](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/svm.html#scores-probabilities):

> This parameters can be accessed through the members `dual_coef_` which
>   holds the product `y_i*alpha_i`, `support_vectors_` which holds the
>   support vectors, and `intercept_` which holds the independent term `rho`.